# How to authorize user based on role in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am working on the React app currently I have different roles for-example ( admin, manager, agent), etc. I want to protect each route if the user is not authorized for that component/page. If the user is not authorize then I want to redirect the homepage. I want to be done after login. I am a beginner and I want to resolve my problem any example would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find different methods but I use HOC. I pass as a child the functionality I want to authorize for. The HOC has props i manually pass to specify which roles are permitted, the license ID ecc... So the HOC implements the auth logic and it renders the children if the user is authorized, instead it renders some error pages.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is RBAC, or Role Based Access Control. I built a library that does most of what you're looking for. You can view the source here for ideas on how to implement it into your own project. https://github.com/schester44/react-access-control

## Examples:

*index.js*

```
import { AccessProvider } from 'react-access-control;

return (<AccessProvder>
  <App />
</AccessProvder>)
```

*App.js*

```
import { useAccess } from 'react-access-control'
import Child from './Child.js'

function App() {
  const { define } = useAccess()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    define({
      permissions: {
        "Admin": false,
        "Moderator": true
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return <div>
    <Child />
  </div>
}
```

*Child.js*

```
import { hasPermission } from 'react-access-control'

function Child() {
  const isAdmin = hasPermission('Admin')
  const isModerator = hasPermission('Moderator')

  return <div>
    {isAdmin && <AdminButton />}
    {isModerator && <ModeratorButton />}
  </div>

}
```

You can also use the `<Show/>` component to show/hide components based on permissions

```
import { Show } from 'react-access-control'


function Child() {
  return <div>
    <Show when="Admin">
      <AdminButton />
    </Show>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a short example based on that repo.

Comment: @John i've added examples

Comment: Thanks, how we will protect route if user is not authorized for that module

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to call this  const { define } = useAccess()

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: can you please help me ?

Comment: Invalid Hook Call is from using a React hook while not inside of a function component.